# How can I call a function when a someone clicks outside the mat-menu?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I want to run a function every time a user opens a mat-menu and then clicks outside it. How can I detect that the mat-menu is opened and that a click event has occurred outside it?
Thanks!

Comment: just in button use menuOpened and menuClosed: `<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (menuOpened)="open()" (menuClosed)="close()">Menu</button>`: NOTE: All events are control by the "matMenuTiggerFor", see the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenuTrigger)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in button use menuOpened and in mat-menu use closed envent

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu" (menuOpened)="open()" >Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" (closed)="close($event)">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

The .ts

```
  open(){
    console.log("open")
  }
  close(event:any){
    //event is undefined if you click outside
    if (event)
         console.log("click inside the menu")
      else
         console.log("click outside the menu")
  }
```

see the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api#MatMenuTrigger),

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @Output menuClosed and menuOpened from matMenuTrigger

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

if you need something more accurate to the events you want to trigger then maybe using @ViewChild you can achieve it
I hope this is helpful for you